# using gluUnproject in ios targeting arm64

Tags: ios, openframeworks, arm64

When I was targeting arm7 gluUnproject was linking fine, now I have had to switch to arm64, the ios compiled glu library that comes with openframeworks complains about there being no arm64 symbols and so it gets ignored, leading to a linker error.

I have found the source code to GLUT

https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php

I don't see any mention of it intending to compile for ios. Can it be compiled for ios arm64 target? can it be downloaded pre compiled from anywhere?

Comment: The OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) and the OpenGL Utility Library (GLU) are separate things. GLUT does not implement `gluUnProject()`. If `gluUnProject()` is the only function you need, it is not difficult to implement yourself from its specification.

Comment: excellent post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as rhashimito pointed out, i can define the function myself. i found an implementation of glu

```
gluUnProject(GLdouble winx, GLdouble winy, GLdouble winz,
    const GLdouble modelMatrix[16], 
    const GLdouble projMatrix[16],
            const GLint viewport[4],
        GLdouble *objx, GLdouble *objy, GLdouble *objz)
{
double finalMatrix[16];
double in[4];
double out[4];

__gluMultMatricesd(modelMatrix, projMatrix, finalMatrix);
if (!__gluInvertMatrixd(finalMatrix, finalMatrix)) return(GL_FALSE);

in[0]=winx;
in[1]=winy;
in[2]=winz;
in[3]=1.0;

/* Map x and y from window coordinates */
in[0] = (in[0] - viewport[0]) / viewport[2];
in[1] = (in[1] - viewport[1]) / viewport[3];

/* Map to range -1 to 1 */
in[0] = in[0] * 2 - 1;
in[1] = in[1] * 2 - 1;
in[2] = in[2] * 2 - 1;

__gluMultMatrixVecd(finalMatrix, in, out);
if (out[3] == 0.0) return(GL_FALSE);
out[0] /= out[3];
out[1] /= out[3];
out[2] /= out[3];
*objx = out[0];
*objy = out[1];
*objz = out[2];
return(GL_TRUE);
}
```